Wrong pallete in Gradient Tree Boost classification
I'm using GTB to classify LULC, and when I'm trying to visualize the image it looks like this:

//Gradient Tree Boost Classification
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileGradientTreeBoost(500).train({
  features : training,
  classProperty : 'lc',
  inputProperties : bands
})

var classified = input.classify(classifier)
var ClassifierPr = classifier.train(points, 'lc', bands)
var ClassifiedImgPrGTB = input.select(bands).classify(ClassifierPr)
var finalimage = classified.blend(classifier)

//Testing Validation
var validation = testing.classify(classifier)
var testaccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('lc', 'classification')
print('Error Matrix GTB :', testaccuracy)
print('Overall Accuracy GTB :', testaccuracy.accuracy())

var kappatest = testaccuracy.kappa()
print('Validation Kappa', kappatest)

//Visualisasi Hasil Klasifikasi Menggunakan GTB
Map.addLayer(ClassifiedImgPrGTB.clip(KutaiKartanegaraSamarinda,{
  min: 1,
  max: 5,
  pallete:
  ['#2a05d6',
  '#ff8323',
  '#00ff0e',
  '#fff100',
  '#d63000']
}, 'LULC 2003'))

I'm doing classification for 5 classes.

Your code is incomplete, but most likely the classes in your training data aren't between 1 and 5.
